# How do I reproduce a DirectoryNotFoundException?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with using Phantom do delete and copy recursively. I have already solved the actual problem which was quite easy checking the below exception anyone could easily do so but can you tell me how to reproduce the problem from visual studio?

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:
>   Could not find a part of the path
>   'build/webui\Views/Web.config'.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String
>   sourceFileName, String destFileName,
>   Boolean overwrite)    at
>   Phantom.Core.WrappedFileInfo.CopyToDirectory(String
>   path) in
>   d:\OpenSource\Build\Phantom2\Phantom\src\Phantom.Core\WrappedFileInfo.cs:line
>   75    at
>   build.$$Execute$closure$23$closure$25.Invoke(WrappedFileSystemInfo
>   file)    at
>   Phantom.Core.Builtins.UtilityFunctions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Action`1 action) in
>   d:\OpenSource\Build\Phantom2\Phantom\src\Phantom.Core\Builtins\UtilityFunctions.cs:line
>   34    at
>   build.$Execute$closure$23.Invoke()
>   at Phantom.Core.Target.Execute() in
>   d:\OpenSource\Build\Phantom2\Phantom\src\Phantom.Core\Target.cs:line
>   81    at
>   Phantom.Core.ScriptModel.ExecuteTargets(String[]
>   targetNames) in
>   d:\OpenSource\Build\Phantom2\Phantom\src\Phantom.Core\ScriptModel.cs:line
>   73    at
>   Phantom.Program.Execute(String[] args)
>   in
>   d:\OpenSource\Build\Phantom2\Phantom\src\Phantom\Program.cs:line
>   57

The problem is that phantom is started from .bat/.cmd file and the build file is sent as an argument and this fails somehow on my Windows 7 x64 machine but doing the exact same thing from within Visual Studio 2008 works perfectly so even if I copy the Views folder I can do so recursively. The original code (that fails from the command line):

```
public override void CopyToDirectory(string path) {
    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    if (Flatten) {
        var combinedPath = Path.Combine(path, Name);
        File.Copy(FullName, combinedPath, true);
    }
    else {
        var combinedPath = Path.Combine(path, PathWithoutBaseDirectory);
        File.Copy(FullName, combinedPath, true);
    }
}
```

Changing the above to:

```
public override void CopyToDirectory(string path) {
    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    if (Flatten) {
        var combinedPath = Path.Combine(path, Name);
        File.Copy(FullName, combinedPath, true);
    }
    else {
        var combinedPath = Path.Combine(path, PathWithoutBaseDirectory);
        var newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(combinedPath);
        if (!Directory.Exists(newPath)) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        }
        File.Copy(FullName, combinedPath, true);
    }
}
```

makes that specific problem go away which is fine I mean figuring it out only took a couple of minutes but trying to reproduce the problem or create a failing test has taken quite a few hours now and I'd like to know why it can't be done or learn how :)

**Edit:** The reason for this is extremely silly but here goes. The base directory in this case would be  "Views" the PathWithourBaseDirectory would be equal to something like "Home/About.aspx" the darn thing would not work in cmd but it did work in Visual Studio. Next thing I know I can't make it run in Visual Studio either so I applied my fix and all tests turn green. I still don't know why...

Comment: If you run as Administrator on the command prompt does it change?  Possibly a lower permissions hidden directory that you can see in Visual Studio/Admin, but can't from a normal command prompt.  Maybe you already checked, but I tend to overlook at first.

Comment: I added a recursive function to sett all file attributes to normal on both subfolders and files. Seems to have done the trick for the permissions part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to know why

Well - there are several problems:

Let's say path is "C:\Foo\Bar.txt" (where Bar.txt is a text-file). 
Now you are calling Directory.CreateDirectory(path).

You try to create the directory "C:\Foo\Bar.txt". However, that "is" already a file.

Then, when creating the file, you combine this path with the file name - a result might be "C:\Foo\Bar.txt\Bar.txt". This however, can not succeed.

Comment: Don't think you read the whole post. I am failing in creating a failing test for this problem. I know what the exception says but how can I prove that my code is actually fixing anything if I can't produce the test confirming it? When running this the same code from VS2008 it works no matter what but from the command prompt it fails.

Comment: I marked it as the answer because it is at least spot on when it comes to the problem.